# How to create a GPT partition from Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, partitioning, gpt, mbr

I have different partitions on my computer:

```
Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1            2048 623128575 623126528 297.1G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2       623130622 625129471   1998850   976M  5 Extended
/dev/sda3       625129472 937701737 312572266   149G 83 Linux
/dev/sda5       623130624 625129471   1998848   976M 82 Linux swap / Solaris

Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

The problem is that I can't install Windows 10 on the first partition (sda1) because it's an MBR partition instead of GPT one. When I try to use Gparted to modify it (I select Device>Create a partition table), the program gives me the error:

```
2 partitions are currently active on device /dev/sda

A new partition table cannot be created when there are active partitions.  Active partitions are those that are in use, such as a mounted file system, or enabled swap space.
Use Partition menu options, such as unmount or swapoff, to deactivate all partitions on this device before creating a new partition table.
```

I actually don't know how to manage it.
Thank you!

Comment: You CANNOT create a separate GPT partition on an MBR disk. The entire disk must be one or the other. Changing between GPT and MBR is likely to erase the entire disk (100% data loss), so do not experiment without a complete set of backups on a different media.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the partition GPT but the partition table, read the wikipedia page to get more information: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_table

**BE-CAREFUL!!!**

The system save your data, you cannot create a GPT partition table where there have already a MBR partition table! You were lucky the system not let you perform the operation, because you could potentially have a lost of your data.

What you have to do is to convert the MBR to GPT, and this cannot be done while the disk is on-line, you have to perform this conversion in to a live system (like gparted live, which provide you also the tools to convert the partition table).

follow the steps at this links to how to proceed: http://slavisa-jovanovic.com/linux/2015/02/19/mbr-to-gpt.html

Anyway I would recommend you to have a data backup before proceed.